# R how to stack image from their matrix value

Tags: r, image, matrix, plot

I got many matrix of size 300*300, which are saved in a list, named L. This is binary matrix, i only have 0 and 1 values.
I  plot image from those matrix (for exemple with c.img).

What is the best way to create a stack of those matrix? I want to create a new matrix, and or the pixel at the (i,j) position, i want to look in all my matrix saved in L, and if one or more matrix have a 1 at this position, then the (i,j) pixel in my new matrix will have value 1, else 0.

Here a pseudo code to help you understand my goal

```
L <- list(rep(matrix(0 or 1,300,300),n)   
new_matrix<-matrix(0,300,300)

new_matrix[i,j]<- max(L[i,j])
```

but this code doesnt work because data is a list. I'm prety sure sure i can achieve this task using  3 loop (i,j,n), but because i got many matrix that'll take too long and i'm looking for a faster solution.

Comment: thanks! Working very well! I found another solution: addition all matrix and in the new matrix all value >1 -> 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
matrix(as.numeric(Reduce(`+`, data) > 0), 300, 300)
```

Sum all matrix then convert values greater than 0 to 1 with `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a multi-dimensional array if all images are the same dimensions.

```
# Two matrices
m1 <- matrix(1,5,5)
m2 <- matrix(0,5,5)

# Placing them in an array (two matrices of dimension 5x5)
my_array <- array(c(m1,m2),dim = c(5,5,2))

# Investigating content of position 1,1 for matrices 1 to 2
my_array[1,1,1:2]
[1] 1 0

# You can even look at larger regions across matrices
> my_array[1:3,1:3,1:2]
, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    1    1    1
[3,]    1    1    1

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```